# Back-porting chrono string literal operators

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to allow the use of string literal operators introduced with `c++14` with `c++11`. I wrote something like that:

```
namespace MYNAMESPACE {
#if __cplusplus < 201402L
constexpr std::chrono::seconds operator""s(unsigned long long int v) {
return std::chrono::seconds(v);
}
#else
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
#endif
}
```

Is it possible? If I well understood the ADL rules, this code shouldn't work because the basic types should belong to the global namespace, so the lookup should be performed in the global namespace instead of using my own namespace.

Comment: Non-standard UDL must start with underscore. So as you already need to violate rules, you could continue by putting that directly in namespace std...

Comment: @Jarod42 I know but there won't be any conflict because already know what the standard says today, I meant I already knows what has been declared in c++14 and since there's an ifdef about c++14 the warning about operator name can be ignored. Just a trick. I could even create a wrapper called operator""_s but the same problem about ADL is present, isn't it?

Comment: @walnut The basic idea was to create something "transparent" for the final user. If I define the operator in the global namespace I should move the "using namespace" in the else branch directly in the header file, so every translation unit includes the file would have a using namespace declaration and I want to avoid that.

Comment: I am not sure why you are talking about ADL in this context. First, I don't think ADL even applies to the literal operator lookup (the types of the argument are determined only after lookup) and fundamental types do not have any associated namespaces or classes to look up in ADL. I think simple unqualified name lookup applies.

Comment: @walnut I could be totally wrong, it's just the reason why I asked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ADL plays any role with user-defined literals. The literal operator is looked up by unqualified name lookup before the argument type of the constructed call is determined.

Therefore the literal operator must always be imported into a scope enclosing the string literal that is supposed to use it.

In your example everything in `MYNAMESPACE` will be able to use `operator""s` (no matter whether from `chrono` or from your custom definition.

Similarly every literal enclosed by a scope that does `using namespace MYNAMESPACE;` or `using MYNAMESPACE::operator""s;` will be able to use it (with the usual rules for unqualified name lookup with `using namespace` applying).

The only issue is that user-defined literal operators not starting with an underscore are reserved and declaring them makes the program *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*, if we are strict about the standard.

---

Another note about lookup: As is, there is a difference between name lookup with the namespace declaration and `using namespace`. `using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;` will behave for purpose of unqualified name lookup as if the literal operator was declared in the global scope, while this is not true for the custom declaration.

You can make them behave equivalently by either using `using std::chrono_literals::operator""s;` instead of `using namespace std::chrono_literals;` or by defining the custom `operator""s` in another namespace `MYNAMESPACE2` that only shares the global namespace with `MYNAMESPACE` and then using `using namespace MYNAMESPACE2;` in `MYNAMESPACE`.

Probably the former mimics the behavior of the `std` namespace better, but only if `MYNAMESPACE` does not share any non-global namespace scope with the point-of-use of the literal.

If the literal operator is used *inside* `MYNAMESPACE`, then the latter is the better approach, because otherwise there might be shadowing of imports e.g. with `std::string_literals;` (though they are also C++14 only).

Comment: yes, you are right, maybe I could create mynamespace2 as inline namespace.